# PHP parser errors in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I just updated my project library folder (with an external to ZF svn) to ZF version 1.11. I'm now getting al kinds of weird errors, related to whitespaces, empty lines, etc. I searched on the internet for quite a while, but can't find a proper answer. I think this is related to some settings in my php.ini file but can't figure it out.

Example of an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /library/Zend/Application.php on line 415 Call Stack: 0.0042 657160 1. {main}() /mnt/hgfs/htdocs/service/public/index.php:0
```

PHP version: `PHP 5.3.5-0.dotdeb.1`

All help would appreciated, I can't wrap my head around it!

Comment: Have you edted the ZF code at any point? Your update may have caused some SVN conflicts

Comment: Usually because short tags aren't enabled. Zend uses full <?php tags but make sure you haven't replaced any, or that they are enabled in your ini

Comment: @Ashley For ZF does not matter whether you use short tags or not. It uses stream wrapper to support it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're running the project on a hgfs mount, probably inside your VM. Try to run your project off the hgfs mount as I found it to be buggy when dealing with these things.

For one, the default mount options don't keep into account that your file and directory properties (uid and gid) probably aren't the same on your guest and host system. Unfortunately, setting these right didn't fix it for me.

The solution I eventually used was to ditch the hgfs driver and mount the files using sshfs. On Debian you can just install it by running `apt-get install sshfs`. I then added an entry to `/etc/fstab`, like this:

```
sshfs#user@host:/path/to/host/dir    /mnt/share    fuse    comment=sshfs,user,rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other 0 0
```

Mounting the share can then be done by running this:

```
mount /mnt/share
```

Hope this helps!